# how to get date from 2 months ago and using it as clause bigquery

Tags: date, google-bigquery

I am trying to get a 2 digit format months from 2 months ago, and it will be used as where clause like this:

```
select a,b,
from x
where month = 'rr'
inner join
select c,d
from
...
```

My most recent query looks like this, resulting 3, instead of 03

```
and MONTH = cast('extract(month from DATE_SUB(DATE "2021-05-27", INTERVAL 2 month)) 'as string)
or
and MONTH = cast('extract(month from DATE_SUB(V_ABC, INTERVAL 2 month)) 'as string)
```

What kind of trick  could I use in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below

```
AND MONTH = LPAD('' || EXTRACT(month FROM DATE_SUB(DATE "2021-05-27", INTERVAL 2 month)), 2, '0')
```

Comment: how if i want to parse with parameters? like this: and MONTH = cast('extract(month from DATE_SUB(V_ABC, INTERVAL 2 month)) 'as string)

Comment: just replace `"2021-05-27"` with respective column name! So, it will be `AND MONTH = LPAD('' || EXTRACT(month FROM DATE_SUB(V_ABC, INTERVAL 2 month)), 2, '0')`

Comment: hoow if i want the data from last year, and my position is in feb 2021. it should be on dec 2020, rite?

Comment: yes - as you asked in your question - it will be 12 - which is December - right? your original question is fully answered - please vote it up and accept . If you have new/more questions - please post the new question and we will be happy to help :o)

Comment: sure will be glad to tag u first if this is works.. still not works. i have to check on something i guess

Comment: Is it string format or do I have to cast-as-string?

Comment: it is string !!